# How to deal with long strings in C++?

Tags: c++, string, performance

My environment is C++03. I need to modify files of about 10000 to 100000 characters (although there can also be larger or smaller files). The modifications include replacing substrings as well as inserting and deleting lines.

- Implementation approach 1: Load the file into a large `std::string`, modify it and write it back into a file. However, inserting in the middle of a string does not have good performance, right?
- Implementation approach 2: Split the string into a `vector<string>` or `list<string>` of smaller chunks (a chunk might be one or several lines), do the manipulations on each chunk and put the whole thing together in the end. I wonder if this has large overhead...

So the question is, what approach is the best? I would appreciate any comments. Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just try both (and other approaches) and *measure*?

Comment: You have to measure it, it's impossible to choose without numbers. Intuitively, I'm with the second approach, but, again, it's just a guess.

Comment: One guess is that reading and writing to the files will take a lot of time compared to moving 10000 characters around in memory. Raw memory bandwidth is typically 10s of GBs per second.

Comment: sgi's original STL had the concept of a rope<>. You might be able to find some source code for it somewhere. documentation here: https://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Rope.html

Comment: @Richard Hodges: Yes, I have read about it in Scott Meyers' book. Unfortunately, it seems to be SGI-only.

Comment: @Fabian i think you'll find that in reality, unless the strings are humungous (tens of megabytes) then std::string will be faster anyway on a caching processor. It's probably why they dropped the rope for the c++ standard.

Answer (score 1):

"100000 characters" doesn't look like a large file to me (that's 100 KB btw). But then again, I have no real experience in text processing. So my advice: test both, **profile them** and don't be surprised if both implementations yield similar results.

> However, inserting in the middle of a string does not have good
>   performance, right?

Not necessary. Due to how systems are designed nowadays, cache locality can make inserting and deleting in the middle of the string/vector surprisingly fast. Again, the only way to know for you specific case is to **profile**.